# Select an option in a nested for loop in Vue js

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, multi-select, jquery-select2

New to **vue** **js** and I am not able to figure out how can I make a select element working.
My code is like this

```
<td>
    <select  class="form-control select2" multiple style="width: 200px;">
       <option v-for="role in user.roles" selected :value="role.id">
           @{{role.display }}
       </option>        
       <option v-if="user.role.id" v-for="role in allRoles">
          @{{ role.display }}
       </option>
    </select>
</td>
```

A user has role(s) associated with him which comes in the form of an array. I have the id and name of the role coming from user object.
allRoles has all the available roles.
What I want to achieve in Vue js is to display all roles in select2 and the role that is user assigned to should be selected.

Edit : Vue Js code.

```
new Vue({
        el:"#userslist",
        ready:function(){   

            this.fetchUsers();
            this.fetchRoles();
        },
        data:{
            selected : '',
            users : "",
            allRoles : "",
        },
        methods:{                               
            fetchUsers:function(){
                this.$http.get('{{route('get.all.users')}}').then(
                    (response) => {
                        console.log(response);

                        this.$set('users',response.data);
                        // success callback
                    }, 
                    (response) => {
                        // error callback
                    }
                );
            },
            fetchRoles:function(){
                this.$http.get('{{route('get.all.roles')}}').then(
                    (response) => {
                        this.$set('allRoles',response.data);
                        $('.select2').select2();                
                    }, 
                    (response) => {

                    }
                );
            },              
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02rafh8p/11/)

Comment: Can you add what your code currently achieves, if anything?

Comment: It displays a select box with roles. The first option is the role that needs to be selected. The rest of the options that populate are the available roles.
Let me try to create replicate it on fiddle, wait.

Comment: Can you edit that into your post? It's better to keep all relevant information there :) also on stackoverflow it's good to tell what you already tried and what the results are, hence my question.

Comment: Okay. The code currently displays user specific role and allroles. I just need to know the syntax. Like

how can I write `role.id( from user.role ) == role.id (from allRoles)`.
I should change the variable names to be more specific .

Comment: You can use just one `option` tag like this : `<option v-for="role in allRoles" selected = "user.role.id === role.id ? true : false">`

Comment: Can you also post your JS code containing the `Vue` instance please?

Comment: Yes sure. I will edit my question.

Comment: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/02rafh8p/11/)